# Two codes; same logic and line of code, one works but other doesn't

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, vector

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56909367/) a couple of hours ago; I want to see if someone can now explain the problem.

One code is about separating items in a grocery; in the end you'll have two(2) bags; a `fragileBag` and a `normalBag`.

Other code separates passengers depending on the office they go for pickup; in the end you'll have three(3) types of passengers; ones that go to rio, ones that go to maya, and ones that request elsewhere.

Both codes use the same logic but the passenger code gives an error on a line that works perfectly on the grocery code.

Just to be clear, BOTH CODES RETURN VALUES OF STRING.

ERROR FROM THE PASSENGER CODE:

> Error (active) E0304 no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=trans, _Alloc=std::allocator<trans>]" matches the argument list dataPractice2 C:\Users\javye\source\repos\dataPractice2\dataPractice2\main.cpp 82

and also:

> Error C2664 'void std::vector<trans,std::allocator<_Ty>>::push_back(_Ty &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::string' to 'const _Ty &' dataPractice2 c:\users\javye\source\repos\datapractice2\datapractice2\main.cpp 82

//GROCERY FUNCTION

```
//separate function
void separateItems(vector<myBag>& newMyVector) {
    for (int x = newMyVector.size() - 1; x >= 0; --x) {
        if (newMyVector[x].getItem() == "eggs" || newMyVector[x].getItem() == "bread") {
            fragileBag.push_back(newMyVector[x].getItem()); //NO PROBLEM HERE
            newMyVector.pop_back();
        }
        else {
            normalBag.push_back(newMyVector[x].getItem()); //OR HERE
            newMyVector.pop_back();
        }
    }
}
```

//PASSENGER FUNCTION

```
//separate function
void separateP(vector<trans>& newMyVector) {
    for (int x = newMyVector.size() - 1; x >= 0; --x) {
        if (newMyVector[x].getXoLoc() == "rio") {
            rioLoc.push_back(newMyVector[x].getXoLoc()); //PROBLEM HERE
            newMyVector.pop_back();
        }
        else
            if (newMyVector[x].getXoLoc() == "maya") {
                mayaLoc.push_back(newMyVector[x].getXoLoc()); //HERE
                newMyVector.pop_back();
            }
            else
                elseLoc.push_back(newMyVector[x].getXoLoc()); //HERE
                newMyVector.pop_back();
    }
}
```

//GROCERY FULL CODE

```
//HEADER
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

#ifndef BAG_H
#define BAG_H
class myBag {
public:
    myBag(); //default constructor
    myBag(string anItemName); //overload constructor
    void addItem(string anItemName); //mutator
    string getItem();//accessor

private:
    string itemName;

};
#endif

//SOURCE
#include"bag.h"

myBag::myBag() {
    addItem("");
}

myBag::myBag(string anItemName) {
    addItem(anItemName);
}

void myBag::addItem(string anItemName) {
    itemName = anItemName;
}

string myBag::getItem() {
    return itemName;
}

//MAIN
#include"bag.h"

void inputItems(vector<myBag>&); //input data function prototype
void displayQuantity(vector<myBag>&); //display data function prototype
void separateItems(vector<myBag>&); //function that separates items; func prototype
void fragBag(vector<myBag>&); //fragile bag function prototype
void norBag(vector<myBag>&); //normal bag function prototype

vector<myBag> myVector; //main vector
vector<myBag> fragileBag, normalBag; //seconday vectors
string item; //global item variable

int main() {
    int option;
    try {
        do {
            cout << "\tMENU"
                << endl << "1) Input Items"
                << endl << "2) Display Quantity"
                << endl << "3) Separate (IMPORTANT)"
                << endl << "4) Display Items in Fragile Bag"
                << endl << "5) Display Items in Normal Bag"
                << endl << "6) Exit Program"
                << endl << endl << "Choose: ";
            cin >> option;

            if (option > 6) {
                throw 404;
            }

            switch (option) {
            case 1: //input
                system("cls");
                inputItems(myVector);
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                break;
            case 2://display
                system("cls");
                displayQuantity(myVector);
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                break;
            case 3: //separate
                system("cls");
                separateItems(myVector);
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                break;
            case 4: //fragile
                system("cls");
                fragBag(myVector);
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                break;
            case 5: //normal
                system("cls");
                norBag(myVector);
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                break;
            case 6: //exit
                exit(0);
            }

        } while (option != 6);
    }
    catch(int x){
        cout << "ERROR, OPTION DOESN'T EXITS" << endl;
        system("pause");
    }

}
//input function
void inputItems(vector<myBag>& newMyVector) {
    do {
        cout << "Enter grocery items || enter letter X to stop: ";
        cin >> item;
        if (item != "x")
            newMyVector.push_back(myBag(item));

    } while (item != "x");
}
//display function
void displayQuantity(vector<myBag>& newMyVector) {
    try {
        for (int x = 0; x < newMyVector.size(); ++x) {
            if (x == 0) {
                cout << "Store bag has " << newMyVector.size() << " items in it. These are: " << endl;
            }

            cout << newMyVector[x].getItem() << endl;
        }

        if (newMyVector.empty())
            throw 404;
    }
    catch (int x) {
        cout << "ERROR " << x << " ,QUANTITY NOT FOUND" << endl;
    }
}
//separate function
void separateItems(vector<myBag>& newMyVector) {
    for (int x = newMyVector.size() - 1; x >= 0; --x) {
        if (newMyVector[x].getItem() == "eggs" || newMyVector[x].getItem() == "bread") {
            fragileBag.push_back(newMyVector[x].getItem()); //PROBLEM WOULD APPEAR HERE, BUT DOESN'T, UNLIKE THE OTHER CODE
            newMyVector.pop_back();
        }
        else {
            normalBag.push_back(newMyVector[x].getItem());
            newMyVector.pop_back();
        }
    }
}
//fragile bag function
void fragBag(vector<myBag>& newMyVector) {
    try {
        for (int x = 0; x < fragileBag.size(); ++x) {
            if (x == 0) {
                cout << "The fragile bag has " << fragileBag.size() << " items in it. These are: " << endl;
            }
            cout << fragileBag[x].getItem() << endl;
        }
        if (fragileBag.empty()) {
            throw 404;
        }
    }
    catch (int x) {
        cout << "ERROR " << x << " ,FRAGILE BAG EMPTY" << endl;
    }
}
//normal bag function
void norBag(vector<myBag>& newMyVector) {
    try {
        for (int x = 0; x < normalBag.size(); ++x) {
            if (x == 0) {
                cout << "The normal bag has " << normalBag.size() << " items in it. These are: " << endl;
            }
            cout << normalBag[x].getItem() << endl;
        }

        if (normalBag.empty()) {
            throw 404;
        }
    }
    catch (int x) {
        cout << "ERROR " << x <<" , NORMAL BAG EMPTY" << endl;
    }
}
```

//PASSENGER FULL CODE

```
//HEADER
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

#ifndef TRANSPORT_H
#define TRANSPORT_H

class trans {
public:
    trans();
    trans(string aName, string anXoLoc, string anXfLoc, string aTime, string aCellNum);
    void setName(string aName);
    void setXoLoc(string anXoLoc);
    void setXfLoc(string anXfLoc);
    void setTime(string aTime);
    void setCellNum(string aCellNum);
    string getName();
    string getXoLoc();
    string getXfLoc();
    string getTime();
    string getCellNum();

private:
    string name;
    string xoLoc; //offices
    string xfLoc; //destination
    string time;
    string cellNum;
};
//SOURCE
#include"transport.h"

trans::trans() {
    setName("");
    setXoLoc("");
    setXfLoc("");
    setTime("");
    setCellNum("");
}

trans::trans(string aName, string anXoLoc, string anXfLoc, string aTime, string aCellNum) {
    setName(aName);
    setXoLoc(anXoLoc);
    setXfLoc(anXfLoc);
    setTime(aTime);
    setCellNum(aCellNum);
}

void trans::setName(string aName) {
    name = aName;
}

void trans::setXoLoc(string anXoLoc) {
    xoLoc = anXoLoc;
}

void trans::setXfLoc(string anXfLoc) {
    xfLoc = anXfLoc;
}

void trans::setTime(string aTime) {
    time = aTime;
}

void trans::setCellNum(string aCellNum) {
    cellNum = aCellNum;
}

string trans::getName() {
    return name;
}

string trans::getXoLoc() {
    return xoLoc;
}

string trans::getXfLoc() {
    return xfLoc;
}

string trans::getTime() {
    return time;
}

string trans::getCellNum() {
    return cellNum;
}

#endif

//MAIN
#include"transport.h"

void inputInfo(vector<trans> &);
void displayInput(vector<trans>&);
void separateP(vector<trans>&);
void rio(vector<trans>&);
void maya(vector<trans>&);
void elsewhere(vector<trans>&);


vector<trans> myVector;
vector<trans> rioLoc, mayaLoc, elseLoc;

string newName;
string newXoLoc; //offices
string newXfLoc; //destination
string newTime;
string newCellNum;

//main not ready. Creating each function one by one to them make it look nice
int main() {
    int option;
    do {
        cout << "MENU"
            << endl << "1) input "
            << endl << "2) output "
            << endl << "3) separate"
            << endl << "4) rio passengers"
            << endl << "5) maya passengers"
            << endl << "6) elsewhere passengers";
        cin >> option;

        switch(option){
        case 1:
            inputInfo(myVector);
            break;
        case 2:
            displayInput(myVector);
            break;
        case 3:
            separateP(myVector);
            break;
        case 4:
            rio(myVector);
            break;
        case 5:
            maya(myVector);
            break;
        case 6:
            elsewhere(myVector);
            break;
        case 7:
            exit(0);
        }
    } while (option != 7);
    system("pause");
}

void inputInfo(vector<trans> &newMyVector) {
    int charSize;

    cout << "How many passangers to register: ";
    cin >> charSize;

    for (int x = 0; x < charSize; ++x) {
        cout << "Name of passanger: ";
        cin >> newName;

        cout << "Office: ";
        cin >> newXoLoc;

        cout << "Destination: ";
        cin >> newXfLoc;

        cout << "Time of pickup: ";
        cin >> newTime;

        cout << "Cellphone: ";
        cin >> newCellNum;

        if (charSize != 0)
            newMyVector.push_back(trans(newName, newXoLoc, newXfLoc, newTime, newCellNum));
    }
}

void displayInput(vector<trans>& newMyVector) {
    for (int x = 0; x < newMyVector.size(); ++x) {
        if (x == 0) {
            cout << "There are " << newMyVector.size() << " passengers. These are: " << endl;
        }
        cout << "-----------------------------Passenger #" << x + 1 << endl;
        cout << newMyVector[x].getName() << endl;
        cout << newMyVector[x].getXoLoc() << endl;
        cout << newMyVector[x].getXfLoc() << endl;
        cout << newMyVector[x].getTime() << endl;
        cout << newMyVector[x].getCellNum() << endl;
    }
}

void separateP(vector<trans>& newMyVector) {
    for (int x = newMyVector.size() - 1; x >= 0; --x) {
        if (newMyVector[x].getXoLoc() == "rio") {
            rioLoc.push_back(newMyVector[x]);
            newMyVector.pop_back();
        }
        else
            if (newMyVector[x].getXoLoc() == "maya") {
                mayaLoc.push_back(newMyVector[x]);
                newMyVector.pop_back();
            }
            else
                elseLoc.push_back(newMyVector[x]);
                newMyVector.pop_back();
    }
}

void rio(vector<trans>& newMyVector) {
    for (int x = 0; x < rioLoc.size(); ++x) {
        if (x == 0) {
            cout << "Num. of passangers to pickup in Rio Piedras is " << rioLoc.size() << " , these are: " << endl;
        }
        cout << rioLoc[x].getName() << endl;
        cout << rioLoc[x].getXoLoc() << endl;
        cout << rioLoc[x].getXfLoc() << endl;
        cout << rioLoc[x].getTime() << endl;
        cout << rioLoc[x].getCellNum() << endl;
    }
}

void maya(vector<trans>& newMyVector) {
    for (int x = 0; x < mayaLoc.size(); ++x) {
        if (x == 0) {
            cout << "Num. of passangers to pickup in Mayaguez is " << mayaLoc.size() << " , these are: " << endl;
        }
        cout << mayaLoc[x].getName() << endl;
        cout << mayaLoc[x].getXoLoc() << endl;
        cout << mayaLoc[x].getXfLoc() << endl;
        cout << mayaLoc[x].getTime() << endl;
        cout << mayaLoc[x].getCellNum() << endl;
    }
}

void elsewhere(vector<trans>& newMyVector) {
    for (int x = 0; x < elseLoc.size(); ++x) {
        if (x == 0) {
            cout << "Num. of passangers to pickup in elsewhere is " << elseLoc.size() << " , these are: " << endl;
        }
        cout << elseLoc[x].getName() << endl;
        cout << elseLoc[x].getXoLoc() << endl;
        cout << elseLoc[x].getXfLoc() << endl;
        cout << elseLoc[x].getTime() << endl;
        cout << elseLoc[x].getCellNum() << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `getXoLoc` returns a `std::string`, not a `trans`.

Comment: escobarveras Look at the question you ask. Copy it yourself and try to compile it. You can't.

Comment: @TedLyngmo you say the same thing as last time.  tkausl already did that. Not much more that can be done bor vTC and move on to a better question.

Comment: I'm sorry if I repeated something already obvious. Who's "tkausl" and what did "tkausl" do?

Comment: No repetition. You asked what can we do to help, I'm basically saying not much. First comment makes the problem clear, but the question is too poorly structured to make any good suggestions on how to fix it.

Comment: @user4581301 I need to take a step back. I'll gladly help if I feel I have info enough. Perhaps I've gotten it and I'm not in a position to see it. I will take a nap.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm not trying to get down on you, there isn't  enough information. There's even less now. The question cannot be answered.

Comment: @user4581301 I was betting on the fact that you didn't want to put me down. Nevertheless, I've been up way too long :-) Cheers!

Comment: @escobarveras Was it really necessary to post this question? You were already told earlier exactly why your code was not working - you are pushing `string`s into a vector that does not hold `string`s. This is clearly stated in your error messages. What is so hard to understand about this?

Comment: look at both codes, run then both; why does one allow me to push_back what I need but the other doesn't? Both are pushing strings into a vector, that doesn't hold strings according to you; also the answer you provided earlier made the code crash; try for yourself the solution you gave me before.

Comment: Too much code to look through. Please trim this down to a [mcve]. For example, you should be able to replace the call to `separateP(myVector)` with `rioLoc.push_back(myVector[0].getXoLoc());`. While this changes the functionality, it should maintain the compile error. Also get rid of the menu -- you only need one code path to get the compile error, so erase the rest from your posted code. Try to get your example code down to, say, 12 lines of code or less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To explain why the second code does not work I first have to explain why the first code appears to work.

```
myBag::myBag(string anItemName)
```

can make a bag out of a `string`. It is a [Conversion Constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor). So when

```
fragileBag.push_back(newMyVector[x].getItem());
```

is compiled, the compiler quietly inserts a call to the `myBag(string)` constructor and you get something more like

```
fragileBag.push_back(myBag(newMyVector[x].getItem()));
```

which makes no sense logically. It says turn an item in a bag into a bag with one item and insert this new bag into still another bag, `fragileBag`.

When you look more closely at `myBag`, you see that it isn't a bag at all. It is a single item and should be renamed to `myItem` or discarded all together in favour of an all-new all-different `myBag` that is a wrapper around a `vector` of `string` where the `string`s represent items. This makes

```
myBag fragileBag;
```

the real bag.

In other words, the only reason the working code works is it doesn't actually do what the naming implies it does. The code compiles and produces the expected result, but is semantically troubled.

This leads to the confusion with

```
rioLoc.push_back(newMyVector[x].getXoLoc());
```

`rioLoc` is a `vector<trans>` and can only hold `trans`. There is no `trans::trans(string)` to convert a `string` to a `trans` so the faulty logic of the grocery  code is exposed. As bag and item have been intertwined in grocery, passenger and transport are combined here.

The fix for grocery described above is relatively straight forward. Passenger will need a slightly different solution with both a `passenger` class to describe the passengers and a `transport` class to describe the means of transport. `transport` will have a `vector<passenger>` member to contain its passengers as well as methods to add and remove the passengers and possibly book-keeping to track the location of the transport, details incompletely specified by the question.

Answer (score 0):

Both codes are pushing `string` values into a `vector` that does not hold `string` values.

Your grocery code uses a vector of `myBag` objects. The code works because `myBag` has a non-explicit constructor that takes a single `string` as input, so the compiler is able to implicitly construct a temporary `myBag` object to push into the vector.

Your passenger code uses a vector of `trans` objects.  The code fails because `trans` does not have a constructor that takes a single `string` as input, so the compiler cannot construct a temporary `trans` to push into the vector.